# How can I vertically align 3 divs in differents containers

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align vertically 3 'title' divs. When the title is one word it must to be in the middle, when is longer must automatically align.
One example of what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/526TD/4/

My problem is that I have my divs in differents containers and not in a same div.

My HTML

```
<div class="related_news_filter">
      <a href="/news/1">
        <div class="round-image"></div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/news/2">
        <div class="round-image">title longeeer</div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title 2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/news/3">
        <div class="round-image"></div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title with more words</div>
        </div>
      </a> </div>
```

My css

```
a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 81px;
 margin: 0 27px 0 8px;
}
.title {     
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 96px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

What I see now:
[image: Titles alignment]

The word "new" and "inbound" are in the first line and not in the middle. They are not correctly vertical aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. The best method accroding to me would be to use the display:table method. Check the below fiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/526TD/29/

```
.related_news_filter {
    display: table;
}

a {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width: 81px;
    margin: 0 27px 0 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.title {
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 96px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

for more methods of achieving this go to the link -http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Is really good this answer as well but I have this problem with the circles :(  oi63.tinypic.com/2nlgsue.jpg, break because the align from the words under

Comment: Can you provide me a link to the circular image so that I can add this to the fiddle and give you a solution?

Comment: Here is the code :) https://gist.github.com/brianstanley/395cf339dde6126d6406
and also you can see live here at the bottom but you must use the chrome emulator and emulate a phone like blackberry z30 because is a phone thing what i'm working for
 http://dc5c1ff9.ngrok.io/
Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/526TD/32/
I'm not sure if its the best way to do it but that is a way to work around that. If the text would be longer just increase the height of the 'title-wrapper'.

Comment: No Problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Just give `vertical-align: middle;` to `a`

```css
a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 81px;
 margin: 0 27px 0 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.title {     
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 96px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="related_news_filter">
      <a href="/news/1">
        <div class="round-image"></div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/news/2">
        <div class="round-image">title longeeer</div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title 2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/news/3">
        <div class="round-image"></div>
        <div>
          <div class="title">title with more words</div>
        </div>
      </a> </div>
```

Comment: Keten I have an issue I need help troubleshooting. Its pretty basic but behavior is really peculiar. Do u have skype?

Comment: @Portal_Zii You can post your issue in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks @ketan , almost but now I have this issue with the circles: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2nlgsue.jpg

Comment: @BrianStanley *"I have this issue with the circles"* Sorry i can't understood. Which issue?

Comment: I replied with an image :), the circles break down because try to align with the words under. The images suppose to stay put

Comment: @Portal_Zii I am using skype but i am outside. You can post you issue on stackoverflow. So many people can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that....

Support is IE10 and up.

```css
.related_news_filter {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 96px;
  margin: 0 27px 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.round-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 81px;
  flex: 0 0 81px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}
.title {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="related_news_filter">
  <a href="/news/1">
    <div class="round-image">title</div>

    <div class="title">title</div>

  </a>
  <a href="/news/2">
    <div class="round-image">title longeeer</div>

    <div class="title">title 2</div>

  </a>
  <a href="/news/3">
    <div class="round-image">title</div>

    <div class="title">title with more words</div>

  </a>
</div>
```

Note: This is not actually aligning the "titles" to one another. It merely lays out all the contents of the link 'containers' in the same way *after* making them all the same height.